# ipython: echo active conifg object (as defined in ``ipython_config.py``) of an ipython instance?

Tags: python, ipython

How can i get the active conifg object (as defined in `ipython_config.py`) of an ipython instance? I'd like to inspect this to check vars are set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config object itself should be stored as the `.config` attribute of any IPython configurable object. If you don't already have such an object, calling `get_ipython()` should get you the InteractiveShell instance that controls IPython.

However, the values from the config are transferred to the configurable objects when they're instantiated, and other things may change those options without going through the config. So to see the actual values in use, just look at the attributes of the objects you're interested in, following the names used in the config.